# connection is busy with results for another hstmt. genexus 9 visual foxpro 9

Tags: sql-server, genexus, visual-foxpro

trabajo con genexus 9 generador visual foxpro9 C/S con sql server.Y desde hace un tiempo una opcion me esta dando este mensaje: connection is busy with results for another hstmt

y realmente no sé por dónde agarrar, seguramente tenga que cerrar alguna conexión , pero no tengo elementos en genexus directos para hacer dicho cierre.

muchas gracias

Espero una respuesta de algún conocedor de este tipo de errores, o que le haya dado y lo haya resuelto.

Comment: ¿Cuál es el código de la opción que te hace generar este error?